# Converting characters like "01APR2020" to date class R

Tags: r, date

I have the following column in my dataframe

```
> df$dates
 [1] "01APR2020" "01JUN2020" "01MAR2020" "01MAY2020" "02APR2020" "02JUN2020"
 [7] "02MAR2020"
```

I would like to format this to an object of Date class, so I want my output to look like this

```
> df$dates
 [1] "01-04" "01-06" "01-03" "01-05" "02-04" "02-06"
 [7] "02-03"
```

And I would like to order them from the oldest to the newest.

Edit:
For example I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
> format(as.Date("01APR2020", "%d%b%Y"), "%d-%m")
[1] NA
```

Thanks!

Comment: Related post: [How to convert datetime format into 'ddmmyyyy' using R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60792199/how-to-convert-datetime-format-into-ddmmyyyy-using-r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `anydate()` function from the [anytime package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=anytime)

```
R> anydate(c("01APR2020", "01JUN2020", "01MAR2020"))       
[1] "2020-04-01" "2020-06-01" "2020-03-01"         
R>
```

It's idea is to *not* require a format for a variety of common and sensible date (or datetime) inputs.  Once they are parsed, putting out day and months is easy too:

```
R> format(anydate(c("01APR2020", "01JUN2020", "01MAR2020")), "%d-%m") 
[1] "01-04" "01-06" "01-03" 
R>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `as.Date` with `format`

```
df$dates <- format(as.Date(df$dates, "%d%b%Y"), "%d-%m")
df$dates
#[1] "01-04" "01-06" "01-03" "01-05" "02-04" "02-06" "02-03"
```

---

Or using `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
df$dates <- format(dmy(df$dates), "%d-%m")
```

NOTE: Both the solutions work on `R 4.0`

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(dates = c("01APR2020" ,"01JUN2020", "01MAR2020",
    "01MAY2020", "02APR2020" ,"02JUN2020" , "02MAR2020"))
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working, I edited the post so you see what I am trying

Comment: @Lucy I can't reproduce the error you showed.  It is working fine for me in R 4.0